# Is there any class so that we can declare double linked list as we declare an array or a stack?

Tags: java

I am looking for an easy way to declare a double linked list as we declare a stack or a queue.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html ?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.LinkedList` is a doubly linked list implementation. For more information check [LinkedList javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)